Windows installer calls msiexec.exe from downloads folder
I have a windows installer built using WiX burn. When I try to install the app by clicking on the .exe folder, it searches for msiexec.exe in the directory where the application installer is located. How can I restrict it to use msiexec.exe from System32 folder instead of current directory?
I checked the source code, but could not find explicit call to msiexec.exe. Seems like the WiX burn bootstrapper calls the msiexec.exe internally.

It sounds like you need to upgrade to the latest version of WiX. WiX v3.5 is over a decade old (maybe even 15 years old) and has known vulnerabilities like this.

Sure, Thanks. I will try with the new version of WiX and post my update here.
